# Android Studio build issue-Concurrent Execution exception

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

[Error coming while trying to build the project](https://i.sstrongtexttack.imgur.com/ZDyjm.png)

Whenever I am trying to build my android studio project the following error comes:

Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 37.323 secs
>   Information:2 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Anyone facing or resloved same kind of issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this by separating into smaller bucket of task

1. build assembleDebug
2. test
3. connectedAndroidTest

i had issues, when i ran assembleDebug and test together in Jenkins as a single task